# IE8 not working with jQuery .show() and working on all other browsers including ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="select_class" style="font-size: 15px;"></a> 
<div class="dropDown" style="display: none;" >
    <!--somecode-->
</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
$('.select_class').click(function(){  
    var isVisible = $('.dropDown').is(':visible'); 

    if (isVisible) { 
        $('.dropDown').hide(); 
    } 
    else { 
        $('.dropDown').show(); 
    } 
    return false; 
});
```

It is giving me error that "null is null or not an object." and its working fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome. Only in IE8 I am getting this issue.

Error is on the following line:

```
var isVisible = $('.dropDown').is(':visible');
```

Comment: try remove the display:none 
then set it to #('.dropDown').hide()
if you have a #(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Also, can you confirm this isn't working - http://jsfiddle.net/9pvbG/

Comment: I want to hide dropdown  for the first time so i need display:none; I tried removing display:none; didnt worked

Comment: Hi Lan, I am using jquery-1.8.3.js version

Comment: @Vani Thanks. And does the fiddle I provided work for you in IE8 or not?

Comment: @Ian i modified his code my this will help i guess that was he was trying to do ...http://jsfiddle.net/9pvbG/1/

Comment: @Vani try this code http://jsfiddle.net/9pvbG/1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I tried this code jsfiddle.net/9pvbG/1 its working in firefox. but not able to run in ie.

Comment: @lan I am not able to run  your code in ie

Comment: ahm i will try to make a project app in my netbeans .. it seems like jsfiddle is not compatible with the old version of IE8 
but you can run but you need to set the document mode into standard IE9

Comment: jsfiddle.net/9pvbG <--- has errors .. it won't work

Comment: @Farnsbert  but as i said earlier its working fine in ie9.... only ie8 has this problem

Comment: i mean the code works
it's working on my IE8 although i just set the browser mode into IE8 and document mode IE8 standards

Comment: @Farnsbert  thank you for your help. It worked When I replace '$' with 'jquery'..

Comment: ah .. i see .. how about in the other browsers ? did they work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked..:)
I replaced '$' symbol with 'jquery' and it worked :-)
something like this:

```
jQuery('.select_class').click(function(){  
        var isVisible = jQuery('.dropDown').is(':visible'); 

        if (isVisible) { 
             jQuery('.dropDown').hide(); 
         } 
        else { 
            jQuery('.dropDown').show(); 
        } 
        return false;  });
```

Comment: it seems you answered your own question .. eheheh